# A hint for multiple choice question

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

[image]

Give me a hint to solve this question,

what should my first step ?

should convert the grams into moles ?

aluminum= (54g/150g)= 36% ( percent composition of aluminum)
sulphur= 64%

0.36x=20 (36 percentage of what is 20)

x=20/0.36
x=55.5 grams

is there a more easy way ? to do in mind

Comment: Stoichiometry problems should generally be solved by converting to moles, using the appropriate stoichiometric rations, and converting back to a desired quantity.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider writing a correctly balanced equation, and then convert grams to moles.

Comment: i have edited the question now,

Comment: That is certainly one way to do it, and the answer appears to be correct.  There are other ways to approach this problem, but I'm not sure they are any easier than your approach. The answer would be given to 1 significant figure, so the correct choice would be 60 g.

Comment: i really appreciate your answer ,

Comment: but this website is very dumb, physics forums is best, any one can ask any type of question, ,, ,,,,, they are saying you have to wait one day for your next question ,,,,,,,, very dumb thinking,

Comment: please block my acount, I don't want to be her e, thankyou for your dumb service , meanwhile physics forums has given me 32+ replies .